# Why is the result of the multiplication not seen from the template with javascript but when inspecting the element in chrome dev tools it is?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

i'm combining with my django project some javascript to do the calculations of a system.
However, it seems strange to me that something as simple as the result of a multiplication is not reflected in the template of my web page but in the chrome dev tools

I attach some images, in the first the total of the multiplication is not reflected, in the second the result of the multiplication is seen but with the chrome dev tools

**Here you do not see the result of the multiplication**
[image]

**Here you see the result of the multiplication**
[image]

**Parte/models.p**y

```
class Parte(models.Model):

    codigo=models.IntegerField()
    quantity=models.IntegerField()
    unit_price=models.IntegerField()
    total_price=models.IntegerField()
    tax_free=models.BooleanField()
    descripcion=models.TextField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    descuento=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # estatus = models.BooleanField()


    # def __str__(self):
    #     return f'{self.codigo}: {self.estatus} {self.descripcion}'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.codigo}: {self.descripcion} {self.quantity} {self.unit_price} {self.total_price} {self.tax_free}{self.descuento}{self.total}'
```

**Parte/forms.py**

```
class ParteForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model=Parte
       fields=['codigo','descripcion','quantity','unit_price','total_price','tax_free']
```

**Presupuestos/models.py**

```
class Presupuestos(models.Model):

    parte=models.ForeignKey(Parte, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.parte}'
```

**calculos.js**

```
function multiplicar(){

    var x=parseInt(document.getElementById('id_quantity').value);
    var y=parseInt(document.getElementById('id_unit_price').value);
    document.getElementById('id_total_price').innerHTML=x*y;

}
```

```
<td>
  {{presupuestosparteform.quantity}}
</td>
<td>
  {{presupuestosparteform.unit_price}}
</td>
<td>
  {{presupuestosparteform.total_price}}
</td>
<td>
  <div class="form-check">
    {{presupuestosparteform.tax_free}}
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" id="addrow" onclick="childrenRow()" value="+" />
</td>
<td>
  <button type="button" onclick="multiplicar();">Button</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Pay extra attention on the formatting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a input element can be settled by the `value` attribute, not by `innerHTML`:

```js
function multiplicar(){

    var x=parseInt(document.getElementById('id_quantity').value);
    var y=parseInt(document.getElementById('id_unit_price').value);

    document.getElementById('id_total_price').value = x * y;

}
```

Comment: wow thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!!